# how to get row field for each node

Tags: views, database, domain-access

i created a field called : (sitename_ar) and i have two rows (two domains) in  {domain} field :

[image]

and i have in my database these two fields {node} and {domain_access} :

[image]

[image]

and i want display in view page:

node : Title

node : Domain (sitename_ar)

i have created a view and i added a Title field and a Global:php field to call rows from database :

[image]

and i addedd those lines :

[image]

but always it display the same field (the first row) :

[image]

How i can Join all those 3 fields and display for each node her domain (with sitename_ar)

Comment: Please paste your php snippets as text, so then can easily be copied and altered.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your php snippet. You request all rows, but `$query->fetchObject();` only returns the first one, as you do not iterate over them.
Use something like `$query->fetchAll()` or `$query->fetchAllAssoc('domain_id');` instead to access all rows.

But, I think there must be smarter ways to handle this. Can't you add a `relationship` from the node to the domain? (I never used domain before). Such relationship would give you the domain entity associated with the node, so you always have the right one.

Comment: i will try adding relationship of nid (node) to the domain

Comment: I meant a relationship in Views (if it exists it should already be there in the advanced section), not like an entity reference or such!

Comment: i have an other solution: adding a table in field node , but i dont konw how i can call domain table and put the "sitename_ar" value to node table

Comment: You need to install the [Domain Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_views) module and look at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/82568/how-do-i-display-the-domain-owner-of-a-node-in-a-view